# What's the PHP code that will compose the below standard object

Tags: php, paypal, stdclass

How to instantiate and populate the stdClass object below?

```
stdClass Object ( [_] => 399.99 [currencyID] => USD )
```

This is the complete stdClass output.

```
stdClass Object ( [Timestamp] => 2014-02-24T22:59:33Z [Ack] => Success [CorrelationID] => 693d0b129fdab [Version] => 71.0 [Build] => 9720069 [Balance] => stdClass Object ( [_] => 399.99 [currencyID] => USD ) [BalanceTimeStamp] => 2014-02-24T22:59:33Z [BalanceHoldings] => stdClass Object ( [_] => 399.99 [currencyID] => USD ) )
```

My goal to to compose the stdClass for BasicAmountType of PayPal's amount value of a transaction.

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate and populate a stdClass object or how to get that object from inside the larger object? In either case, the solution is extremely simple and I would have expected to at least see what attempts you have made to do this.

Comment: I am trying to instantiate and populate a stdClass object exactly like the stdClass data above.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to cast an array to an object.

```
$obj = (object) array('_' => 399.99, 'currencyID' => 'USD');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
$obj = json_decode(json_encode(['_' => 399.99, 'currencyID' => 'USD']));
```

This is rather the way you got your object in the code.